# ServiceStack Soap 1.2 HTTPS Client

Tags: c#, soap, https, servicestack, soap1.2

I have a `ServiceStack` based Soap Client, which operates correctly for HTTP but when I try to use HTTPS it gives me this error

```
ServiceStack.WebServiceException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; ex
pected 'http'.
Parameter name: via ---> System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'http
s' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.ValidateCreateChannelPar
ameters(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannelCore(Endp
ointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.InternalCreateChannel(En
dpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.ServiceChannelFactoryOv
erRequest.CreateInnerChannelBinder(EndpointAddress to, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateServiceChannel(En
dpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateChannel(Type chan
nelType, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address
, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at ServiceStack.WcfServiceClient.Send(Message message)
   at ServiceStack.WcfServiceClient.Send[T](Object request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ServiceStack.WcfServiceClient.Send[T](Object request)
   at ElectronicServiceInterface.ESIClient.Login()
```

I am using a self signed certificate, but I am able to use curl to call my Soap service successfully. This to me indicates that the issue is at the client end.

My code goes along the lines of

```
using (var client = new Soap12ServiceClient(Uri))
{
    var request = new MyRequestObject { Username = Username, Password = Password };
    var response = client.Send<MyResponseObject>(request);
}
```

The above shows example request/response DTO class usage.

What do I have to do to make it work with HTTPS without using config files, only code?

Comment: please add your code/configuration of the services hosting.

Comment: @silver There is no config. I have added a little more code, which at least shows the `send` call that triggers the exception. The soap service itself is not a ServiceStack based service (only client), but regardless the code doesn't get as far as actually hitting the server at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with config file is that it isn't always straightforward and sometimes plain unpractical. On top of this ServiceStack promotes config-less coding model.

I managed to achieve the required functionality with the following SSL-neutral client:

```
public class SoapServiceClient : Soap12ServiceClient
{
    public SoapServiceClient(string uri) : base(uri)
    {
        if (uri.StartsWithIgnoreCase("https://"))
        {
            var binding = (WSHttpBinding)base.Binding;
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe your problem is in your config file, 
 try to add  to the binding tag.
 regarding to this [ServiceStack.IntegrationTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.IntegrationTests/ServiceStack.IntegrationTests.Host.Web/Web.config.classic) you should have

```
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Endpoint_BasicHttpBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Endpoint_WsHttpBinding">
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

but in this test, it is only configured to work on HTTP not HTTPS so all you have to do is to change `<transport clientCredentialType="None" />` to `<transport clientCredentialType="transport" />`

Comment: I don't actually have a config file. So creating is probably the way to go. I'll try it thanks.

Comment: you can use the mentioned link in my answer, it will help you to for-fill all needed configurations, also this link could help https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Config-API

Answer (score 3):

you need to have 2 separate base addresses, one for the HTTP and one for HTTPS.

you can define it in configuration file or in you code that performs the hosting.

Comment: How would I do it in code? I'd rather avoid config if I can. It's only a test application nothing serious.

Comment: when you create your service host you need to provide an array of Uris so provide both protocols 
(new ServiceHost(MyService, new []{"http://myService/","https://myService/"}))